# ImageView setMaxHeight or getWidth doesn't work

Tags: android, android-imageview

I have this code:

```
holder.ImageMain.setMaxHeight(holder.ImageMain.getWidth());
```

My intention is to have a square imageview if the image is big and horizontal. the code will set a height that is the same as the width.

But for some reason it's not working. The imageView has been long and horizontal.

Do you have any idea what's wrong with it?

Comment: try using holder.ImageMain.setHeight(holder.ImageMain.getWidth());

Comment: setHeight doesn't exist

Comment: hope this will work holder.ImageMain.getLayoutParams().height=holder.ImageMain.getWidth()

Comment: That may work. But I solved it using android:adjustViewBounds= "true" as suggested by Aracem. this way it can also take care of landscape images very well. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use 
`android:adjustViewBounds= "true"`

or to a more controled case, use instead a custom ImageView that in the onMeasure method adjust it size like you want. For example here are an example to create a 16/9 ImageView

```
public class SixteenNineImageView extends ImageView {

    public SixteenNineImageView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public SixteenNineImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public SixteenNineImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    public SixteenNineImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

        final int width = getMeasuredWidth();
        final int height = (width * 9) / 16;
        setMeasuredDimension(width, height);
    }
}
```

Comment: adjustviewbounds works. I dont understand the second part. what is it for? is it going to make the height to be 9/16 of the width? if so, why not do 
                    holder.ImageMain.setMaxHeight(holder.ImageMain.getWidth()*9/16);?

Comment: First of all, you have a small and simple custom view that free yourself of put that code always you want a 16/9 image. Futhermore, this works include when you scale up or down the image. It always has that aspect ratio.
Both solutions are valid, but first one is for a puntual situation, the other is to encapsulate that functionallity.